# Dynamic file manager windows or linux

Tags: linux, windows, nsfilemanager, file-management

Is there a dynamic file manager:

Example file structure:

Project 1

- design
- functional
- technical

Project 2

- design
- functional
- technical

To be able to query by project or by type:

- Project 1, Project 2, ..
- Project 1 design, Project 2 design

Something like multi-criteria search by user defined criteria.
If there isn't an existing solution - can I simulated it?